# ScalaTest: testing web apps with multiple browsers

Tags: selenium, scalatest

I am trying to have the same integration test for a web app with multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, InternetExplorer, etc. one after the other).

[ScalaTest plus Play](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play) has these traits AllBrowsersPerTest and AllBrowsersPerSuite. Did anyone wrote something similar but not tied to a web framework? (The web app I am testing is based on Wicket, not Play.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using [PageObject](https://www.pageobject.org/).

PageObject uses all available browsers (i.e. those with a configured [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)) by default (in my case Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer).

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pageobject</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_${scalaBinaryVersion}</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I found the code of [PageObjectTour](https://www.pageobject.org/downloads/PageObjectTour.pdf) helpful to get started.

Note: PageObject 0.1.0 uses its own version of ScalaTest 3.0.0 because of [a bug](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/931) not yet fixed in the ScalaTest trunk. So I had to remove my own dependencies to `org.scalatest:scalatest`.